# How to convert a response to an appropriate form?

Tags: php, request

I use Binance API. 
The PHP function gets file contents of url:

```
https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=4h&limit=1
```

I receive such a response:

```
[[1528545600000,"7635.01000000","7650.00000000","7566.00000000","7621.15000000","3246.04484200",1528559999999,"24674635.12120312",57351,"1932.28202000","14685353.70584041","0"]]
```

How to get the second value? (7635.01000000)

Comment: Use a library? https://github.com/jaggedsoft/php-binance-api

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the second value use this:

```
$receivedData = '[[1528545600000,"7635.01000000","7650.00000000","7566.00000000","7621.15000000","3246.04484200",1528559999999,"24674635.12120312",57351,"1932.28202000","14685353.70584041","0"]]';

$jsonDecodeData = json_decode($receivedData); 

$secondValue = jsonDecodeData[0][1];

echo $secondValue; //7635.01000000
```

Comment: This is the reason why I ask the question. I have tried json_decode, but the problem is that JSON doesn't accept "[ ]" brackets.
So I get such an error: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 64

Comment: what do you mean by JSON doesn't accept "[ ]" brackets? can you please explain with an example.

Comment: jsonDecodeData just returns what is written in receivedData. But I have solved the problem with str_replace and regex.